# why am i getting a syntax error in extjs tree editor?

Tags: extjs

why am i getting this error

"SyntaxError: function statement requires a name"

for the code in this

[How to use ExtJS TreeEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427353/how-to-use-extjs-treeeditor?newreg=51f8d208aab642488587b0ced0dec778)

Comment: Which version of Ext JS are you using? `Ext.tree.TreeEditor` is Ext JS 3 component, it is no longer exists in current Ext JS 4.

Comment: i am using  3.4 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines, out of context, are not valid Javascript (they should be enclosed in curly brackets to form an object literal). That's the source of the parse error in your question:

```
onTreeNodeDblClick: function(n) {
    treeEditor.editNode = n;
    treeEditor.startEdit(n.ui.textNode);
}

onTreeEditComplete: function(treeEditor, o, n) {
    //o - oldValue
    //n - newValue
}
```

Here's how you can fix it. Please, take notice of my comment... You're likely to run into further errors once you fix the first ones:

```
var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    // The following function won't be defined, you'll have to configure
    // a working root to make this example work... And possibly more!
    root: this.getChildren(),
    height: 300,
    loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader(),
    useArrows: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    listeners: {
        dblclick: onTreeNodeDblClick
    }
});

var treeEditor = new Ext.tree.TreeEditor(tree, {}, {
    cancelOnEsc: true,
    completeOnEnter: true,
    selectOnFocus: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    listeners: {
        complete: onTreeEditComplete
    }
});

// It seems that the intention of the author was to declare independent 
// functions (as opposed to object methods).
function onTreeNodeDblClick(n) {
    treeEditor.editNode = n;
    treeEditor.startEdit(n.ui.textNode);
}

function onTreeEditComplete(treeEditor, o, n) {
    //o - oldValue
    //n - newValue
}
```

Comment: If I were you, and if your own research doesn't yield anything interesting, I'd ask another question here. If you can put together a working code sample to build upon (ideally in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)), you'll surely get an answer in no time!